# How do I stop the execution of a command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to stop the execution of a command if the users balance < the money he bets. Everything works fine but the only problem is I am not able to stop the execution of the command if the users input bet > his balance.

I am trying to stop the execution at
`await message.channel.send(embed = error_bet_bal)`

Here is my code :

```
await message.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(title='Please Enter The Amount to Bet', color=0xFFFF00))
        
        
        
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        bet_str = msg.content
        bet = int(bet_str)
        if bet>users_balance:
            await message.channel.send(embed = error_bet_bal) #displays that the users bal is less than what he is trying to bet. I am trying to stop it here but after displaying the error message it continues to the while loop.
       
while bet<1:
            if bet >= 1:
                break
            else:
                await message.channel.send(embed = error_bet)
                await message.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(title='Please Enter The Amount to Bet', color=0xFFFF00))
                

                msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
                bet_str = msg.content
                bet = int(bet_str)
```

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `return` to end the function

Below is the revised code

```py
await message.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(title='Please Enter The Amount to Bet', color=0xFFFF00))
        
        
        
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        bet_str = msg.content
        bet = int(bet_str)
        if bet > users_balance:
            await message.channel.send(embed = error_bet_bal)
            return
     
       
while bet<1:
            if bet >= 1:
                break
            else:
                await message.channel.send(embed = error_bet)
                await message.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(title='Please Enter The Amount to Bet', color=0xFFFF00))
                

                msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
                bet_str = msg.content
                bet = int(bet_str)
```