# How to stop the execution if "!stop" found in the discord channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How to stop the execution of the script if the bot receives the "!stop" command from the channel?
I am just learning to create such bot, so my current code is:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
@bot.command(name='stop')
async def here(ctx):
        while True:
            print(2)
            time.sleep(15)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

So I have 3 selenium drivers working on different machines and I want to set up communication through a discord channel (each machine will have its own bot). Currently, the machine which opens a specific URL first that machine will send a stop message to the channel and close the connection with the chat, while the other two machines should stop immediately after the message.

So, the ideas

```
page_opened = True
while page_opened = True:
     do something and listen
     if there is a message stop:
         page_opened = false
```

How should I handle this idea with discord bots? Any hints?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64473974/how-do-i-stop-the-execution-of-a-command-in-discord-py says you should just return something (though I'm not sure if it is a function). You could always try: `while running:` and setting running to true before you start, but false once `!stop` is called.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama thanks for your comment. but I have not fully understood the offered solution either....

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an `exit()` or `sys.exit()` command whenever you want to stop the execution of *any* Python program. For example:

```py
import sys

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(name='stop')
async def here(ctx):
    sys.exit()  # Stops execution of the program

bot.run(TOKEN)
```